# Multiple index answers Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program where the user would input their word and they'd have the definition printed before them by scraping DuckDuckGo's auto response box.

```
import requests
import sys
import codecs
import os
import time
def end():
    steve = 1
p1 = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q="
p2 = input().replace(" ", "+")
p3 = p1 + p2
timeout = 0
def find():
    global timeout
    timeout += 1
    print(timeout)
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        res = requests.get(p3)
        res.raise_for_status()
        playFile = open('RomeoAndJuliet1.txt', 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            playFile.write(chunk)

        playFile.close()

        f = codecs.open('RomeoAndJuliet1.txt',encoding='utf-8')
        contents = f.read()
        newcontents = contents.replace('"','*').replace("'", '^')
        page = newcontents
        i = page.index("Abstract") + 11 
        defn = page[i: page.index("*", i)]
        f.close
        if timeout == 8:
            print('timed out')
            exit()
        if defn == '' or defn == 't' or defn == 'rce':
            find()
        if defn != '' or defn != 't' or defn != 'rce' or defn != 'err':
            open("demofile.txt", "w").write(defn)
            print(defn)
            end()
    except:
            print('err')
            end()
find()
end()
os.remove("RomeoAndJuliet1.txt")
```

Occasionally I would get unwanted definitions of `t`, `src`, or just a blank character. I have adjusted that by making the program reload the page and check again.

My main issue is that when the program does have to refresh, it outputs the anticipated answer as well as all the unwanted answers listed above.

```
>>> 
== RESTART==
bill gates
1 #Number of refresh attempts
2
3
William Henry Gates III is an American business magnate, investor, author, philanthropist, humanitarian, and principal founder of Microsoft Corporation. During his career at Microsoft, Gates held the positions of chairman, CEO and chief software architect, while also being the largest individual shareholder until May 2014.
rce
rce
>>>
```

I'm trying to only get the anticipated answer and store it in a text file, but it keeps getting overwritten by the unwanted answer

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed

```
if defn != '' or defn != 't' or defn != 'rce' or defn != 'err':
        open("demofile.txt", "w").write(defn)
        print(defn)
        end()
```

to

```
if defn != '' and defn != 't' and defn != 'rce' and defn != 'err':
        open("demofile.txt", "w").write(defn)
        print(defn)
        end()
```

I only changed the `or`'s to `and`'s.

Now `demofile.txt` contains the anticipated answer and this if part will only be executed if `defn` is not equal to the specific values

The file was overwritten for two reasons in conjunction.

- The first reason being you used `or` in combination with `!=`, so when one `!=`-clause was satisfied which would always be the case since `defn` cannot be all of them at the same time it would execute this if part.
- The second reason being your call to find() inside find() here:

  ```
  if defn == '' or defn == 't' or defn == 'rce':
          find()
  ```

  Since that appears before:

  ```
  if defn != '' and defn != 't' and defn != 'rce' and defn != 'err':
          open("demofile.txt", "w").write(defn)
          print(defn)
          end()
  ```

  After the first call to `find()` failed to return the anticipated answer it would then call `find()`, which would (maybe) call `find()` again, and so on, until maybe the anticipated answer would be returned by one of those `find()` calls and thereby ending the consecutive `find()` calls. The "failed" `find()` call(s) would then overwrite the "correct" `find()` call answer because after the "correct" `find()` call is finished, the other `find()` calls get executed in reversed order of which they were initially called until the respective ends of the respective functions are reached .